# How can I add a variable by one whenever a click event fires

Tags: javascript, math, increment

Im new to Javascript, and I want to build a basic program that displays and increment by one whenever a user clicks on a button or link. For example, when event is fired by a click. The counter should display a 1. Then, when a user clicks wherever i placed the event listener; the counter should display 2. etc.

```
function addByOne(e) {
 var i = 0;
 if (e = true) {
   elMsg.innerHTML = ++i;
 }
}

var elMsg = document.getElementById('count');
var el = document.getElementById('selection');
el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  addByOne(e);
}, false);
```

The bottom portion of my code is the event listener i added to my HTML. But i'm mostly worried about the top portion of my code. Whenever i click on a element to make the event fire it just displays a zero. It doesn't increment by one from there.

Comment: You set `i` to `0` at event handler, `e` is `event`, `if(e = true)` assigns `true` to `e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare `i = 0` in the `addByOne` method, it will be initialized to 0 on each click. It should be declared outside of the function. Also, `e = true` will overwrite the event object being passed to the event handler.

```
function addByOne(e) {
    elMsg.innerHTML = ++i;
}

var i = 0;
var elMsg = document.getElementById('count');
var el = document.getElementById('selection');
el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    addByOne(e);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` is set to `0` at each event handler call, `e` is event, `if(e = true)` assigns `true` to `e` : `event`.

You can use `HTMLElement.dataset` to store data at the element, `Number()` to convert string to number, `+ 1` to add to the number, reset the value at `.dataset` property of element

```js
function addByOne() {
   if (elMsg.dataset.i === undefined)  {
     elMsg.dataset.i = 1
   } else {
     elMsg.dataset.i = Number(elMsg.dataset.i) + 1
   }
   elMsg.innerHTML = elMsg.dataset.i;
}

var elMsg = document.getElementById('count');
var el = document.getElementById('selection');
el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  addByOne();
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="count">count</div>
<div id="selection">click selection</div>
```